# Corona: Image cropping

Tags: lua, coronasdk, crop, masking

how to crop an image selected from camera roll in corona sdk?

I have tried masking  [following this tutorial](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/useful-crop-library) 
but this gives me colored background with my cropped image on it. I need cropped image alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local localGroup = display.newGroup()

local backGround = display.newImage(localGroup,"backGround.png")
local imageForCrop = display.newImage(localGroup,"path.png")

local mask = graphics.newMask("mask.png")

localGroup:setMask(mask.png)

--then Capture , or if you don't need to capture circle you can use easy the display.captureBounds(boundsData)
```